# HAML and Nested Layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Essentially what I want to do is have a root application.haml that contains the core css and js then the site layout goes  something like

- application.haml

  - marketing.haml(s) with their own css's and markups
  - userbackend.haml(s) with their own css's and markups
  - siteadministrators.haml(s) with their own css's and markups

So I tried doing this by adding a sub_layout to my controllers so for instance my home controller which is a marketing sections gets:

```
def sub_layout
    "marketing"
  end
```

controllers for the actualy application that the users use

```
def sub_layout
   "userapplication"
end

def sub_layout
   "siteadministrators"
end
```

then in the application.haml I call
   = render(:parital => "layouts/#{controller.sub_layout}")

this returns "undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass"

Like many on here I'm very new to rails and haml especially though I do have experience with .NET MVC and the Spark View engine

any thoughts on what this haml looks like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you suspected, there is a standard and much, much better way of doing this.
Your application.haml:

```
!!! XML
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Title
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'global'
    = yield :styles
  %body
    #content
      = yield
    = yield :scripts
```

And then your marketing.haml:

```
- content_for :styles do
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'marketing'

- content_for :scripts do
  = javascript_include_tag 'marketing'

%h1 It's Marketing time!
```

Anything in the 'content_for :styles' block gets executed in the context of it's respective yield in the layout. You don't need to have a content_for for every yield, if you have multiple, the results get concatenated.

Enjoy!

Comment: I have a follow up question though - How do I use this in context with layouts? So Application->Vegetables->Create Vegetable Application->Vegetables->Edit Vegetable should all get the 'vegetable.css' file

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. In my example application.haml is the layout. By the way, in rails you really should name them application.html.haml, marketing.html.haml etc.

Comment: Sorry didn't expect you to respond so fast I edited my follow up

Comment: So in that case I would have a vegetables.layout file

Comment: It would be called vegetables.html.haml and live in the layouts dir. I think a technique like this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts would solve your problem the best.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
= render :file => "layouts/#{controller.sub_layout}"
```

Calling a method on the controller is problematic in that it potentially exposes your method as an action.  Since you're just returning a string, you could do this (e.g.):

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  @@sub_layout = "marketing"
  cattr_reader :sub_layout
```

A better option is probably to abstract this into a helper method where you can lookup the value with the controller class and return the layout file name. That would keep the controllers cleaner.

Comment: This works however your "better option" comments makes me think I have to rethink how I'm doing this -- kinda surprised with all of the sensible defaults in ROR there's not a clear cut way to do this as it seems really obvious to me